# Numpy, Finding indices of similar elements across two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got two 1 dimensional sorted numpy arrays, call them x and y, about 250 items each, with similar but not identical ranges.
What I'd like as an output are the values that the two arrays line up at, and where this happens, within the range where the two arrays overlap.

So if I had
`x = [1, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 5, 6]`
`y = [2.1, 3.6, 5.2, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

I would return
`x_ind = [1, 4, 5]`
`y_ind = [1, 2, 3]`
`values = [2, 4, 5]` or `[2.1, 3.6, 5.2]`

(which array it pulls from for the value is less important as the real arrays are finer resolution than this example)

so that I can say that `x[xind] ~= y[yind] = value`,
[Pictured are the two actual arrays plotted as their value at each index against their indices. What I'd like is an output that, thinking visually, cuts out the section of the green line that exists within the value range of the blue line, and gives me the corresponding locations for each point on the green line that lines up with a value on the blue line, where on the blue line, and at what value they match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPwqT.png)

I've already tried
`xind = np.where(np.logical_and( x >= min(y), x <= max(y) ))`
for picking out the overlapping range, which is fine, but that doesn't give me the indexes of corresponding "matching" values, so on we go.

I've tried
`xind = np.where( np.isclose(x,y) )`
with varying tolerances, and this successfully gets me a list of indices for values in x that are near values in y by whatever standard of nearness I pick and gets the values I've hit via x[xind], which is great, but this doesn't give me the indices in y that I'm comparing against for a given "matched pair," which is what I really need.

Comment: I think `np.searchsorted` gets pretty close to what you want. You can probably adjust the input data to get the nearest index rather than the lower or higher index.